# confirm before onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onbeforeunload, onunload

I need to prompt the user before he leaves the page, on confirmation close the tab and if not do nothing. I want to send an ajax call on `onbeforeunload`.

My only idea was to write handlers for both `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
window.onunload = function(){
    $.get(
        "http://www.mysite.com/php/myhandler.php",
        { data: 1 }
    );
};
```

but this did not seem to work in jsFiddle

Comment: The page is being aborted before the ajax can complete. This is a case where your ajax call must be synchronous.

Comment: done!!!!try the code!!

Comment: +1,never thought about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in this fiddle-->
[Perfectly working fiddle!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/fxtBC/)

```
 function warning(){
            if(true){
                return "You are leaving the page";
                 $.ajax({
                        url: "test.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: values to send
                        })
            }
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = warning;
```

Comment: But it won't prompt the user before leaving

Comment: Yeah, if user presses ok, then make call and close tab, if not, then just do nothing

Comment: do you want to keep the tab open if cancelled??

Comment: That code does nothing. :( I'm fairly certain that Chrome blocks all confirm/prompt/alerts in onbeforeunload.

Answer (score 0):

Just place em all inside `onbeforeunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    $.get(
        "http://www.mysite.com/php/myhandler.php",
        { data: 1 }
    );
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

Comment: But won't that execute the AJAX no matter the prompt outcome? I only want it to execute the call if the user is actually leaving.

Comment: Do it like this then: Promt the user, if yes do AJAX, if no don't AJAX and return false.

Comment: You mean like this?

    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
     if(prompt('Are you sure you want to leave?'))
     {
         $.get(
           "myphp.php",
            { val: 1 }
       );   
     }
     else
        return false;
   };

Comment: yeah pretty much that

Comment: If I do that, it ignores the prompt() and just prompts you with "false"